# Showing list of files in current directory while navigating? (Screen, Linux)

Tags: linux, ls, gnu-screen, watch, cwd

I'm looking for a way to have list of all files/folders of the current directory in my terminal that updates automatically and runs while I'm actively navigating and editing files.

I imagine it to be somehow possible with a terminal multiplexer. But I don't know how you could notify another process about the change in the current process.

If I run `watch ls -a` in one split-view, it will only update when files in that same directory change, not when the directory of my other split-view changes.

Basically, I want it to look somewhat like this:
[image]

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: I was going to suggest Midnight Commander as well, though I don't think it updates the listing dynamically. If you have Emacs, you could easily have a shell buffer communicate with a Dired buffer, perhaps using `inotify-watch`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the PID of shell 1 and use it's process information (CWD) to update `ls` in shell 2.

shell 1:

```
$ echo $$
24678
```

shell 2:

```
$ watch ls /proc/24678/cwd/
```

Now you can use `cd` in shell 1 and the view in shell 2 will be updated in shell 2 (per default every 2 seconds).

An nice gimmick: You could use `watch -d` to highlight the differences between successive updates (file creations/deletions etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) or a similar program does what you want? You can overlay the terminal window with two lists of files, there are keyboard shortcuts, but you can still switch to a full shell.